# How to get tag from UIImageViiew in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have added tap gesture on `UIImageView`. I want to get the tag from it when I tap on the image. Please tell me how can I do it?

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tap_post_image:)];

tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
[tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];
[cell.beizer_image setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
[cell.beizer_image addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
[cell.beizer_image setTag:indexPath.row];

- (void) tap_post_image: (id)sender
{
    NSInteger the_tag = ((UIView*)sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"tap post image is called");
    NSLog(@"TAG is %ld",(long)the_tag);
}
```

Above code crashes the app.

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash. What's the complete error message and which line causes the crash?

Comment: That's because the "sender" is not a UIView. You are wrongfully typecasting it into one.

Comment: yup.  the param to tap_post_image is a gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you really need to provide details of the crash on your question, one obvious issue is that you assume the `sender` parameter of your `top_post_image:` method is a `UIView`.

This is incorrect. The parameter will be the gesture recognizer, not a view. But you can get the view from the gesture.

The code should be:

```
- (void)tap_post_image:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSInteger the_tag = gesture.view.tag;
}
```

On an unrelated note you need to work on your naming conventions. In Objective-C (as well as many other languages), it is common practice to use what is called "camel case'. Your method should be named `tapPostImage:`, not `tap_post_image`.

Answer (score 0):

You will crash because sender in your code is not uiview, uiimageview.
sender is UITapGestureRecognizer class.
You should do

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapImageView:)];
    [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.sampleImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.sampleImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.sampleImage setTag:99];

    - (void)tapImageView:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"Sender is a %@ class",NSStringFromClass([sender class]));
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender);
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)tapGesture.view;
        NSLog(@"imageView.tag = %d",imageView.tag);
    }
```

I hope it helps!